# PHP. Работа с регулярными выражениями

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
[club 88888| ****] текст 2 [club 88888| ****]текст 3
```

Надо убрать все содержимое скобок вместе с ними

Использую регулярное выражение `[.*?]+`, но выделяются только звездочки.

Подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не экранируете скобки, правильнее будет сделать вот так:

```
$string = '[club 88888| ****] текст 2';
echo preg_replace('/\[.+\]+\s?/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помог :3

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = '[club 88888| ****] текст 2 [club 88888| ****]текст 3';
echo preg_replace('/\[.*?\]+/', '', $string);
```